# Render partial view in MVC using action result, ObjectContext disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, partial-views, dispose

I am trying to populate a partial view using the following in my view:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("AppointmentsView", "Appointment", new { id = Model.PatientId });}
```

My action result is as follows:

```
    public ActionResult AppointmentsView(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new WaysToWellnessDB())
        {
            IEnumerable<AppointmentDiary> appointments = context.AppointmentDiaries.Where(a => a.PatientId == id).ToList();

            var accountUsers = context.AccountUsers.Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.AccountUserId.ToString(), Text = rr.FirstName + " " + rr.LastName }).ToList();
            ViewBag.AccountUsers = accountUsers;

            var location = context.Locations.Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.LocationId.ToString(), Text = rr.LocationDesc }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Location = location;

            return PartialView("/Views/Patient/Appointment/_ViewAppointments.cshtml", appointments);
        }
    }
```

My partial view is as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.DateTimeScheduled)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.AppointmentLength)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.AccountUser.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.AccountUser.LastName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Location.LocationDesc)</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.AttendedStatusId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AppointmentStatus, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "appointmentStatusId", onchange = "alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is falling down, saying the following:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

I tried using .Inlcude in my linq query, but this hasn't worked.. any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Comment: There are two navigation properties, Location and AccountUser. Both have to be included.

Comment: Include is the way to go with Location and AccountUser, what 'didn't work' about it?

Comment: Its not letting me include either though...

Comment: @user3284707 Are you sure you are using `System.Data.Entity`?

Comment: Ahhh thank you that was it!! I forgot about that being needed!

Answer (score 1):

The answer as posted by Alexander Derck was that I needed to include System.Data.Entity in my using statements at the top, then the following worked.

```
    public ActionResult AppointmentsView(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new WaysToWellnessDB())
        {
            IEnumerable<AppointmentDiary> appointments = context.AppointmentDiaries.Include(p => p.AccountUser).Include(p => p.AttendedStatus).Include(p => p.Location).Where(a => a.PatientId == id).ToList();

            return PartialView("/Views/Patient/Appointment/_ViewAppointments.cshtml", appointments);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented "using" block, which disposes the object once done executing the "using" block. So when you are trying to access the virtual properties "item.AccountUser.FirstName", as the context object has already disposed, it is throwing "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed" error.
As posted by Alexander Derck, using include will resolve this issue because you are including all the required virtual properties in advance when the context object is still alive.
hope this explains.

Comment: please refer this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) to understand how entity framework loads related data.